# Сортировка выборки из mysql по сумме нескольких строк

Tags: mysql, sql

Допустим есть табличка rate и в ней пять столбцов. В первом столбце хранятся имена, а в остальных какие-то числа. Что указать в `ORDER BY` для того, чтобы по порядку выводились те записи у которых сумма этих чисел больше?

```
INSERT INTO `rating_uni` (`id`, `name`, `r1`, `r2`, `r3`, `r4`, `r5`) VALUES
(47, 'Name1', 0, 2, 1, 1, 1),
(48, 'Name2', 0, 2, 2, 1, 0),
(49, 'Name3', 1, 0, 1, 1, 0),
(50, 'Name4', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(51, 'Name5', 3, 0, 0, 0, 1),
(52, 'Name6', 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
(46, 'Name7', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(53, 'Name8', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
```

вот пример: у id 47 в сумме получается 0+2+1+1+1 = 5, у id 48 в сумме получается 0+2+2+1+0 = 5, у id 49 в сумме получается 1+0+1+1+0 = 3. Сортировка должна происходить по этим сумам

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM rating_uni
ORDER BY r1+r2+r3+r4+r5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Name, Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, SUM(Column1 + Column2 + Column3 + Column4 + Column5) AS Total
FROM MYTABLE
ORDER BY Total;
```

Comment: в данном случае sql подсчитывает абсолютно все значения и выводит их сумму. Мне же нужно подсчитать сумму из каждой строки по отдельности

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Name, Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5,
(select SUM(Column1 + Column2 + Column3 + Column4 + Column5) from MyTable mt where mt.id=MYTABLE.id) AS Total
FROM MYTABLE
ORDER BY Total;
```

Comment: Да получилось спасибо)

Comment: А нафига ему нужна эта сумма в выходном наборе? да ещё получаемая через коррелированный подзапрос?